# Something wrong with odd sum

Tags: c++

This code does not show the correct output.

I need help at the sum, odd. I am not sure if the vector is ok. What I need to do is *"to calculate and display a vector that has as product elements the corresponding element on the first row and the first column."*

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhp2z.png) is an image with the code when is running.

```
The input and the output are:
Let A be a quadratic matrix with a maximum of 20 rows and columns, with integer elements.
Enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix: M =4
A[1,1]=2
A[1,2]=3
A[1,3]=4
A[1,4]=5
A[2,1]=6
A[2,2]=2
A[2,3]=3
A[2,4]=4
A[3,1]=5
A[3,2]=6
A[3,3]=2
A[3,4]=3
A[4,1]=4
A[4,2]=5
A[4,3]=6
A[4,4]=2
2       3       4       5
6       2       3       4
5       6       2       3
4       5       6       2

Enter the number of the column to be summed = 3

The sum of the items on the column is32779 // here should be 24 . 
The number of odd elements in A, located below the main diagonal, is 1 //here should be 2 ,not 1
4       3       2       5
3       2       6       4
2       6       5       3
6       5       4       2
16 9 4 30
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Let A be a quadratic matrix A with a maximum of 20 rows and columns, with integer elements." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix A: M = ";
    int rows_and_columns;
    cin >> rows_and_columns;

    // Reading the elements of the matrix A
    int matrix_A[20][20];
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows_and_columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows_and_columns; j++) {
            cout << "A[" << i << "," << j << "]=";
            cin >> matrix_A[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Matrix display
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows_and_columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows_and_columns; j++) {
            cout << matrix_A[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // the sum of the elements on column sum_column, sum_column being which column to make the sum
    cout << endl << "Enter the number of the column to be summed = ";
    int sum_column;
    cin >> sum_column;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows_and_columns; i++) {
        sum += matrix_A[i][sum_column];
    }
    cout << endl << "The sum of the items on the column is" << sum << endl;

    // below the main diagonal, count how many odd numbers there are
    constexpr int n = 0;
    int number_of_odd_numbers = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            if (i + j < rows_and_columns + 1) {
                if (matrix_A[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                    number_of_odd_numbers++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The number of odd elements in the matrix A, located below the main diagonal, is " << number_of_odd_numbers << endl;

    // changing the elements between them
    int x = rows_and_columns - 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= rows_and_columns; j++) {
        std::swap(matrix_A[j][1], matrix_A[j][x]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows_and_columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows_and_columns; j++) {
            cout << matrix_A[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // calculation and display of vector B
    int vector_B[20];
    for (int k = 1; k <= rows_and_columns; k++) {
        vector_B[k] = matrix_A[1][k] * matrix_A[k][1];
        cout << vector_B[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does it compile? does it not produce correct output? Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Indices start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Please format your code. If people are suppose to help you, they need to be able to easily read the code. That means having good and consistent indention and spacing, as well as good variable names. Currently, the code is too tangled with weird indention and spacing to be readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a matrix 20x20 in resize regardless of the players input.
I would recommend a dynamically sized array using `std::vector` or something similar.
The extra size is usually fine, but in this program it has caused the program not to crash at the first for loop when it should have crashed.

Arrays in C++ have the range [0, size). You are currently using the range [1, size]. All of your for loops should start at index 0, and use the `<` operator instead of the `<=` operator.
If you array had been the right size you would have out of bounds of the array and caused a crash.

Under the comment `//count how many odd numbers there are`, assuming `n` is meant to be `0`, `i` is always going to be larger than `n` since you set `i` to `2` so the loop is never run.

Beyond that I do not know what the program is meant to do, but keep in mind that arrays have the range [0, size) and you should be able to figure it out.